# How was Rayleigh and Planck approach different in developing a theoretical description for black body radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation, history

How was Rayleigh and Planck approach different in developing a theoretical description for black body radiation? I know that Planck took discrete values for $<E>$ but what was Rayleighs approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rayleigh's approach is classical in nature. This a brief outline

1. We want to figure out what is the amount of energy radiated from a cavity per unit wavelength. In order to do that we need to know "how many" modes live within the cavity. That is called the density of states, which can be shown to be

   $$
    \varrho = \frac{8\pi}{3\lambda^3}
    $$

   It is important to realize here that is a classical result from  electromagnetism.
2. The density of states per unit wavelength is simply

   $$
    \varrho_\lambda = \left|\frac{d}{d\lambda}\varrho\right| = \frac{8\pi}{\lambda^4}
    $$
3. In thermal equilibrium (again, a classical result), each of these modes will have energy $kT$, so that the energy density per unit wavelength is

   $$
    u_\lambda = \varrho_\lambda kT = \frac{8\pi k T}{\lambda^4}
    $$
4. Now we poke a small hole in the cavity and measure how much radiations comes out. I will skip the details, but it is going to be proportional to $u_\lambda$:

   $$
     r_\lambda = \frac{2\pi c k T}{\lambda^4}
     $$

This last equation is Rayleigh's model for the radiation of a black body. And it is derived from two classical principles: electromagnetism and thermodynamics. Plank's approach, on the other hand, is based upon the discretization of the radiation field, a pure quantum result